# How do I fix my graphics settings - messed up openGL I think!

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

Bit of an annoying one - I was trying to fix the jaggy edges on my wobbly windows a little while back and I ended up somehow completely disabling all of my pretty stuff. I believe I was trying to replace an openGL driver with another using command line and now somehow I have no driver at all :(

When I run Briquolo it runs at about 2fps. Just did that as a test so it seems I can run OpenGL stuff, just extremely poorly, which suggests my graphics card is pretty much redundant in my machine.

Is there a program or package I can run to check/reinstall it?

Thanks a lot for any contributions.

Comment: describe what exactly did you do please.

Comment: I can't remember! I know that's dumb. Is there no diagnostic tool I can run or anything like that?

Comment: Try reinstalling your graphic drivers in "Additional Drivers" and restart your comp

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would close this one out by letting people know that I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 (finally) and it sorted it all out.

I was kinda resigned to doing a total reinstall but the update seemed to do the trick!

Hmm no when will I upgrade to natty?

Comment: Also the new GLX Cairo Dock RUUUUUULES!!